# David♦ Moderator resignation

Tags: discussion, moderation

Well, here is a post that even a year ago I never thought I would be writing.

I've been part of this site for six years to the day, January 21, 2014. My interest in blender caused me to get more and more involved with BSE so much so that I was one of our first three [elected moderators](https://blender.stackexchange.com/election/1). Over the years my enthusiasm for SE grew - this was the best place to get answers for blender questions. Slowly life moved on, and I used blender less and less (as you could probably guess from my declining answer rate); yet I was always still here, almost out of duty for this community.

Now we get to the present. I'm not going to rehash all that has transpired (the history goes back a few years, and greatly accelerated in the last four months), but the fact is that *I no longer feel good about supporting SE.*
**So I'm resigning as a mod, and stepping away from SE as a whole.**

Let me be clear, my departure has nothing to do with BSE, or any of you the users and my friends. It is solely based on the actions of SE and what kind of company SE has become.

As with anything that one embarks on for *years* of one's life this change leaves me saddened. Saddened for how SE has changed, and saddened because of all that I'll miss: hunting and destroying socks, helping users, interacting with other mods, but most of all the friends I gained along the way.

I'd be remiss if I did not thank some of the people that I have had the pleasure of interacting with over the years. You have helped shape this site, 
you *are* this site. Further you helped shape me. I'm hesitant to make a list like this because I know I will not be able to list everyone.

In alphabetical order a non-exhaustive list of users that have had a impact on me and this site:

[**batFINGER**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/15543/batfinger) You supply endless python answers, like the ones that came before you [CodeManX](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/1363/codemanx), [ideasman42](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/55/ideasman42), [pink vertex](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/2271/pink-vertex) and many more. Your answers are filled with a lifetime of wisdom. Your expertise in python shows through the amazing volume of answers of have written.

[**cegaton**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/1853/cegaton) Thank you for working to keep this site running - for years. Your endless edits, persistent comments and all around blender knowledge is a real asset to the community.

[**CharlesL**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/20/charlesl) Our activity did not overlap much, but I will never forget the [ebook](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/conversation/space-pizza-by-charlesl-and-david) we coauthored, fun times. Definitely one of the most memorable moments.

[**Duarte Farrajota Ramos**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/19307/duarte-farrajota-ramos) You were one of the few active users in BSE's lull. You stepped up to be a full blown mod when no one else would. I remember you pumping out good answers, seemingly on fire. Even now, you still have passion for this community - singly handily editing whole tags.

[**gandalf3**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/599/gandalf3) Wow, where to start? Back when I first joined you were the one I wanted to be like. Top dog on the site - you could answer everything. You made gifs a standard part of answers "gandalf style gifs." Your demeanor through chat was unwavering, and your keen sense for internet privacy was something I always aspired to.

[**GiantCowFilms**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/3127/giantcowfilms) First off Thank you for building (twice) [blend exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), without that service BSE would have a **lot** more dead blend file links littered all over the place. Now this might be a surprise but thank you for the many times we disagreed in chat, through that I better learned to see other people's perspective, and hopefully better communicate.

[**iKlsR**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/12/iklsr) BSE's longest serving mod, first appointed in June of 2013 and served this site well since. Back in the day before we graduated, you were our only active mod. You alone had to deal with all my flags and incessant pings to fix stuff, both in chat and on the meta. Also the only user who [knows it all](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8888?m=27779715#27779715).

[**Jerryno**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/7777/jaroslav-jerryno-novotny) Aside from having one of the coolest user ids on the site, you have provided a wealth of knowledge through hundreds of answers. I personally have learned much from you. Your contributions to BSE will always be remembered.

[**Nicola Sap**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/16395/nicola-sap) You are the next wave of active users. I've seen you post great answer after great answer. Keep it up, just do not burn out too quickly.

[**Ray Mairlot**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/241/ray-mairlot) You unlike many from your era are still around and active. You have done the unrewarding work: edits and comments, the work that keeps this site running. For that I am forever grateful.

[**VRM**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/6204/vrm) You were definitely part of "the old crew". Super active back in 2015 both in chat and on BSE. Your answers were always spot on and helpful. I will always remember our interactions with fondness.

[**X-27**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/5426/x-27-wants-to-reinstate-monica) The pyromaniac stalker of the renderfarm :) You are one of the users that seemingly was always in our chat, another of "the old crew". I'll never forget our fun banter, nor your stack exchange video.

Without detailing each one, many others I knew from [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22096768#22096768):

[Gwen](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/25/gwen), [Scalia](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/6385/scalia), [Shady Puck](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/20508/shady-puck) [someonewithpc](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/3078/someonewithpc), [stacker](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/29/stacker) [TARDIS Maker](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/8262/tardis-maker), [Thom Blair III](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/2173/thom-blair-iii), and [Vader](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/1476/vader).

---

I leave this site with a word or two of advice.

- Remember what it was like to be a noob, the things we take for granted, many reading your answers will not know.
- Mind the tags. I was once called the tag master you will have to replace me for that job, please keep reign on those unwieldy categorizations.
- 2.8 brought a ton of new users and questions to this site (more then anything else in BSE's 6 years and 8 months history), you are going to have to find a way to filter out all the LQPs and keep the gems.
- Mods: always stay pingable in [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm), that is important.

Its been fun, disappointing, tiring, invigorating, draining, exciting, enlightening and so on. I would not trade my experiences here away. Were I able to go back these six years, sure there are some things I would of changed, but I'd do it all again.

Farewell all.

[image: logging out]

Comment: Thanks for being the mentor we needed around here. Hope I'll see you around again some day. PS: You should have posted this GIF https://media.giphy.com/media/gFwZfXIqD0eNW/giphy.gif

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos The difference is the terminator said "I'll be back" not so sure that is true of me.

Comment: One can hope for better stack exchange days :)

Comment: owwwwww, nooooooo

Comment: Live long and prosper!

Comment: Today is a sad day, you never read into these until it hits your site. The community is what makes any site and I hope SE realizes that one day before they lose the core of what built and maintained many of these communities.

Comment: Understandable. I never was very active anyway, even though I still have the reward T-Shirt. I have quit long ago over inter user quarrels and I still am on page one of the users. Something to think about. Big projects often forget that it's people who make the site big, not the software. Where can I read about the big problems?

Comment: Guess I found it. The more politically correct people want to be, the less correct they become.

Comment: @David, thank you for all you have done for this site and the network.  It's sad that it's ending like this, but we can only control our own actions.  Thank you for standing up for what you believe in.  I hope we meet again in a better place.

Comment: @MonicaCellio hold on while I pick up my jaw off the floor (yes seeing a comment from you was a huge surprise). wow How do you even find posts like these? You will forever have legend status for us network power users. Thank you for everything *you* have done. PS I hope you don't mind when I [borrowed](https://web.archive.org/web/20200102070658/https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) your avatar.

Comment: @David this post is [linked from Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342039/162102); that's how I found it.  Thanks for the kind words.  I was touched by your change in name/gravatar!

Comment: I actually cried when I read this. You will be missed, and the site, will be so much less for it. I've always admired you incredible commitment to the duty of moderating this site. Thanks for keeping all things tidy as they should be :). I will miss your presence on chat immensely.

Comment: It is very sad to see how one known as always ready to help to the site goes away. I wish you keep only the best moments you had from SE and I only hope site continues working which will be harder without your invaluable contribution.

Comment: Sad to see you leave. Given the circumstance this is totally understandable. Hope we'll see you around in some other part of the Blender community!

Comment: Thankyou for the mention it is very humbling.  Thankyou for your advice, patience, diplomacy, statesmanship, responsiveness, understanding.  Will do my best to heed the advice re noobs and not put on my big bad wolf hat and... Hopefully you are not lost to blender and  without the _"addiction"_ of BSE can get down and create away.  Oh and also may  you find something to fill the sweeping and hat fetish.  You will be sorely missed. Adios Amigo.

Comment: Thank you for the very kind words! I myself learned so much from your posts and the site you co-build. I too am using the site less and less, I barely visit twice a week now. Am also sickened what is happening with SE. I wish you the best in all the next endeavors David!

Answer (score 28):

Thank you for your meticulous tag management.
Thank you for your tireless review queue sweeps.
Thank you for your steadfast flag handling.

You poured so much energy into keeping the cogs of this site going for years. We appreciate you for that. But more than that, thank you for being our friend. Your advice is well taken.

Thank you for everything, we'll miss you.