# First year with you and Blender. Thanks guys!

Tags: discussion

Today is exactly 1 year since I installed Blender and made my first ever 3D... donut.
And also 1 year since I visited this site for the first time to get help :).

### You're all awesome, thank you!

Mad props to everyone for helping others navigate Blender.
It's thanks to your answers that I actually *know what I'm doing* most of the time :).

---

Moonboots - the best [cookies](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/177797/78972) in the business
Mr Duarte Farrajota Ramos - keeping this site a nicer place to hang around
Ray Mairlot - making sure people don't get lost here since 2013
batFINGER - thanks for all the [nightmares](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165293/78972) :)
Robin Betts - aside from knowing everything, thanks for being the nicest person
Gorgious - [modifier magician](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164578/78972) and [node wizard](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164425/78972) :).
susu and troy_s - learning [all](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/175110/78972) the [stuff](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/174228/78972) like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/92301/78972) from real pros is a nice change after art school :).

And also big thanks to others like Robert Gützkow, lemon, vklidu, Martynas Žiemys and Leander for their great answers.

---

That's it. I love it here.

Comment: I don't want to be a killjoy but, while I appreciate the spirit and sentiment (and your involvement on the site), I'm not *entirely* sure that the [meta](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) is the place for this...

Comment: I understand, I just didn't know where else to post this :).

Comment: Good old StackExchange, where being nice and saying thank you is officially discouraged. Glad to see that not everyone is taking the rules too serious.

Comment: Thank you @RobertGützkow :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank, keep up the enthusiasm and great involvement.

Without trying to kill the mood, I do agree with Ray that Meta is not really the best place for this sort of post.

I think this post is probably symptomatic of the fact that we often deal with the same relatively small circle of users here at Stack Exchange, but in a somewhat cold and neglecting way that SEs policy enforces, without any sort of warmer social interactions whatsoever.

Instead of the usual flag and delete I'll try to turn this opportunity into a learning moment.

Not sure if you are aware of [chat rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=blender.stackexchange.com).

They often go unnoticed, and users who never used them can't easily be coaxed into one. They are however an adequate place for the otherwise almost absent act of socializing on this barren Stack Exchange.

It's been slowly getting pretty deserted there for the past few years, and only got worse after the recent moderator resignations [1](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2690/david-moderator-resignation) & [2](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/a-goodbye-to-the-community).

Maybe we can make good use of your enthusiasm and revive the once prosperous and lively chat rooms. [Render Farm](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm) was created far before I knew about this site, and is the go-to off-topic general chat room around.

Feel free to chat away, I wouldn't mind getting to know some frequent users here a little better, maybe we can lure more users back in. Beware that users who never visited a chat room before don't get chat notifications even for @ direct mentions until you first visit a chat at least once.

Be sure to mention them in a comment linking to the particular room so they can join in.

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestions :). I'll be sure to try chatrooms for expressing my enthusiasm :).